# Use existing JPAQuery as subquery

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, querydsl

I have an instance of `JPAQuery<?>` and need to retrieve the count. However, since the table may contain many items (millions), I want to limit the count to a given maximum, say 50,000.

The current QueryDSL-Code effectively does this:

```
query.fetchCount();
```

Now my desired modifications are quite trivial in raw sql:

```
select count(*) from (<whatever query> limit 50000);
```

However, I do not know how I would express this in querydsl. The following code is not correct, because `.from()` takes an entity path, but `query` is a query:

```
JPAExpressions.select(Wildcard.all)
    .from(query.limit(50000))
    .fetchCount();
```

I am using querydsl 4.

Comment: Why would you even want to limit a count query? `count(*)` is fast as hell anyways. And currently you could do like `JPAExpressions.select(Wildcard.all)
    .from(entity)
    .fetchCount().limit(50000)` (code might be wrong)

Comment: unfortunately `count(*)` is slow if the query that it's counting on doesn't have a proper index (e.g. not unique I think?). In my case, it does _not_ scale indefinetely

Comment: Umm... I think you are kind of wrong here. Just ran a count on ~4m entries in less than a second and that table definitly has no index whatsoever

Comment: that's nice, but unfortunately I have other circumstances. I executed a count on an oracle 12.1 database with filters perfectly matching an index and it takes several minutes. the oracle optimizer seems to sometimes do a full table scan or other grotescly slow operations if the potentially matching subset is very large and/or the statistics are off.

Comment: You got that resolved? How did you do it? Can you share? I'm running into the same problem and the answer here is bad

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I ever solved this exact scenario and insteads worked around it, e.g. not using querydsl but a raw jpql query instead

Answer (score 0):

`JPAExpressions.select(Wildcard.all)` returns a child of SimplyQuery, which you can call limit on.

```
JPAExpressions.select(Wildcard.all)
    .from(entity)
    .limit(50000)
    .fetchCount();
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where does `query` come into play in your example?

Comment: `JPAExpressions.select(Wildcard.all)` IS a query. Look at the documentation to see how it works. You can still call `.from(...)` too. I just didn't include it.

Comment: @Felk you shouldn't need that query. I doubt you can create a separate query from a query. At best you can copy the query and count on the second. `JPAExpressions.select(Wildcard.all) .from(entity).limit(50000).fetchCount();` is most probably what you need (maybe add your where clause)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the underlying entity, only the query itself

Comment: also, wouldn't your example limit the result set _after_ counting? meaing it counts _all_ entities, and then limits the result (which is always 1 row: the count) to 50000